# How to change variable value from regular HTML code to string

Tags: javascript

Could someone tell me how could I change the value with HTML code to a regular string? Example:

```
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
=> "<h1>Hello World!</h1>"
```

Current code:

```js
var myH1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
console.log(myH1);

// Prints: <h1>Hello World!</h1> instead of "<h1>Hello World!</h1>"
```

```html
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
```

Comment: `myH1` is a HTMLElement (object). Why do you expect it to be a string?

Comment: I know but how to transfer it to string?

Comment: `myH1.outerHTML`

Comment: With [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: ritaj, you can write it as an answer ( not as a comment ) ... thx!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can do like this :

```js
var myH1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];

myH1 =`"${myH1.innerHTML}"`
console.log(myH1);

//Or

var myH1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
console.log(myH1.outerHTML);
```

```html
 Output => "<h1>Hello world!</h1>"
```

Comment: Now, you can check  : myH1 =`"${myH1.innerHTML}"`

Comment: The OP asked for the output to be `"<h1>Hello World!</h1>"` as opposed to `"Hello world"`. I think your code should be `myH1.outerHTML` rather than `myH1.innerHTML`.

Comment: The `.innerHTML` part is not relevant for this question